# Typescript: How do I ensure a generic type is subset of JSON?

Tags: json, typescript

I'd like to do this:

```
interface IJSON {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean | IJSON |
                 string[] | number[] | boolean[] | IJSON[];
}

function iAcceptOnlyJSON<T subsetof IJSON>(json: T): T {
  return json;
}

let good = {
  message: 'i work',
};

let bad = {
  date: new Date(),
};

// good is a subset of IJSON so everything works!
iAcceptOnlyJSON(good);

// bad is not a subset of IJSON so this should give me an error
iAcceptOnlyJSON(bad);
```

Of course, there is no "subsetof" in Typescript. Is there a way to get this functionality in typescript?

Comment: What exactly do you think "JSON" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close - the language feature is called [generic parameter constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), and the keyword to use instead of `subsetof` is `extends`:

```
function iAcceptOnlyJSON<T extends IJSON>(json: T): T {
  return json;
}
```

The error message for `iAcceptOnlyJSON(bad)` is

```
"Argument of type '{ date: Date; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IJSON'.
      Property 'date' is incompatible with index signature.
        Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | IJSON | string[] | number[] | boolean[] | IJSON[]'.
          Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'IJSON[]'.
              Property 'length' is missing in type 'Date'."
```

This is not foolproof however - everything that's [structurally compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) with a `string`, but is not a string will pass too.